# Javascript "mousemove" event sometimes doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, mousemove

I have a codepen.io example I've been working on to create a pure js collapsible side panel that is also resizable. The example works 70% of the time, but every-so-often resizing the panel will result in no "mousemove" events being emitted and the panel simply freezes (i.e. not tracking the mouse x position). I can't find the issue myself, wondering if anyone can shed some light on this one. Maybe there is a better approach to adding / removing event listeners for this kind of work that I've not thought off.

The meat of the js logic looks like the following:

```
const divider = document.querySelector(".divider");

const startSlide = event => {
   const viewportWidth = window.visualViewport.width;
   const width = viewportWidth - event.clientX;
   divider.style.width = `${width}px`;
};

const stopSlide = event => {
   window.removeEventListener("pointermove", startSlide, true);
   window.removeEventListener("pointerup", stopSlide, true);
};

const initSlide = event => {
   window.addEventListener("pointermove", startSlide, true);
   window.addEventListener("pointerup", stopSlide, true);
};

divider.addEventListener("pointerdown", initSlide, true);
```

To reproduce the issue just attempt to slide the divider panel left and right a couple of times, eventually, it will bug!

[broken codepen example](https://codepen.io/JarvisPrestidge/pen/YRpwBv?editors=1001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it becomes more reproducible if you quickly drag up after selecting the dividing bar.  Adding a drag event listener shows that the drag on the divider is consuming the event

```
  divider.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {
   console.log("DRAG");
  }, true);
```

You probably need to prevent the element from consuming the drag event

Answer (score 2):

@kriddy800 put me on the right track with looking at drag events. The fix for this particular issue and many related dragging type problems is to cancel the native `onDragStart` event, which in turn will stop future `onDrag` events from firing and masking the wanted `onMouseMove` events.

```js
divider.ondragstart = () => false;
```

A great explanation of everything drag related: https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop